# <video> with CSS opacity property appears unusually dim on Chrome 54 for Mac only

Tags: html, css, video, opacity

A `<video>` tag with the CSS `opacity` property is more dim on the latest version of Chrome (54) on a Mac than other browsers (including Chrome 54 on Windows and Chrome 53 on Mac). This is very apparent when opacity is set to a low value like 0.2. I've witnessed this on multiple systems.

Run this code on the latest version of Chrome (currently 54) on a Mac then on another browser to see the difference. How can this code be changed to make video opacity on Chrome for Mac consistent with other browsers?

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title>Video</title>

<style type="text/css">

video {
    opacity: 0.2;
}

</style>

</head>
<body>

<video src="https://demos.churchthemes.com/maranatha/wp-content/uploads/sites/8/2016/10/lighthouse-loop.mp4" autoplay loop></video>

</body>
</html>
```

https://jsfiddle.net/68q91qwc/4/

[Screenshot Comparison](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ClBoO.jpg) - This shows the difference.

Thank you for looking at my question.

Answer (score 0):

I am also getting this issue, anyone found a solution?

edit:

In response to this I've implemented temporary fix, firstly use the following to apply a .mac or .pc class to the body:

```
if (navigator.userAgent.indexOf('Mac OS X') != -1) {
  $("body").addClass("mac");
} else {
  $("body").addClass("pc");
}
```

and then target this with a chrome only media query.

```
@media all and (-webkit-min-device-pixel-ratio:0) and (min-resolution: .001dpcm) {
    #home.mac selector {
        opacity: 0.3;
    }
}
```

Comment: In response to this I've implemented temporary fix, firstly use the following to apply a .mac or .pc class to the body.

Comment: I only saw the problem with Chrome 54+ on Mac so detecting OS like this would make opacity wrong for other browsers. If this is a browser bug that ends up being fixed then there would be a future problem too. I decided not to use video with opacity in order to avoid having to detect OS/browser, but an approach like this may be the only option for now.